# Pagination button on Products and Brands page not working in Prestashop 1.7.5.1

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I had some issue with some modules in Prestashop and I rebuilt the installation on Prestashop v1.7.5.1 by restoring some databases related to Category, Manufacturer, attributes, features, products images, etc.

Everything is working well except when I browse Brands or Products pages. The pagination button to go on page 2 doesn't work.

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://store.copiscan.com/qc/10-imprimantes?page=2" class="js-search-link">2</a>
```

I checked in console and I don't have any error related to Script. But the URL looks like called with a class js-search-link.

How to open the URL on a click?